# populating a link table in a script - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

so i have a script like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(80)
)

CREATE TABLE nationality
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(80)
)

INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('Fred');
INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('Mary');
INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('Jane');

INSERT INTO nationality (name) VALUES ('Canadian');
INSERT INTO nationality (name) VALUES ('American');

CREATE TABLE person_nationality
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    person_id INTEGER,
    nationality_id INTEGER
)
```

The final table is a link table to link people to nationalities. Is there a way to auto populate this? like I know the first three should be linked to Canadian and the final one should be American. But I dont know how to make a script to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `insert`:

```
with people (person_name, nationality_name) as (
  values ('John', 'Canadian'), ('Fred', 'Canadian'), 
         ('Mary', 'Canadian'), ('Jane', 'American')
)
insert into person_nationality (person_id, nationality_id)
select p.id as person_id, n.id as nationality_id
  from people i
       join person p on p.name = i.person_name
       join nationality n on n.name = i.nationality_name;
```

[Fiddle Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cdb96457f3b37db428293e6dc93b43d6)